# the BroadcastReceiver does not read the all sms length

Tags: android, sms

The BroadcastReceiver doesn't read all the word of the sms is just read some word from it please can any one help me?

public class SMSBReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
    private static MessageListener mListener;

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Bundle data = intent.getExtras();
    if (data != null) {

        Object[] pdus = (Object[]) data.get("pdus");
        for (int i = 0; i < pdus.length; i++) {
            SmsMessage smsMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);

            if (smsMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress().toString().equals("Samba.")) {
                String message = smsMessage.getMessageBody().toString();
                mListener.messageReceived(message);
            }
        }
    }
}
public static void bindListener(MessageListener listener){
    mListener = listener;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to append all sms:

Change this:

```
String message = smsMessage.getMessageBody().toString();
```

To

```
String message += smsMessage.getMessageBody().toString();
```

So final code will be like -

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Bundle data = intent.getExtras();
    if (data != null) {

        Object[] pdus = (Object[]) data.get("pdus");
String message = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < pdus.length; i++) {
            SmsMessage smsMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);

            if (smsMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress().toString().equals("Samba.")) {
                 message += smsMessage.getMessageBody().toString();
                mListener.messageReceived(message);
            }
        }
    }
}
public static void bindListener(MessageListener listener){
    mListener = listener;
}
```